# Error when combining sass-loader with css-modules

Tags: sass, webpack, css-modules

I'm getting the following error when using SASS's `map-get`.

```
ERROR in ./src/special.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Unknown word (11:14)

   9 |
  10 | @mixin mediaquery($name) {
> 11 |     @media #{map-get($breakpoints, $name)} {
     |              ^
  12 |         @content;
  13 |     }
  14 | }
```

This is only happening when I use both the `sass-loader` and another loader.

I [first thought](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss/issues/46#issuecomment-252509793) this was caused by the PostCSS Loader, but it seems like it's the sass-loading causing problems and not transforming the scss when using `css-modules`.

I've created a sample repo illustrating the problem: https://github.com/tiemevanveen/sass-css-components-fail-example.

You can use the different branches to test:

- `master`: CSS Modules + SASS
- `postcss` CSS Modules + SASS + PostCSS
- `log-source`: Uses CSS modules + SASS + [Custom source logging module](https://github.com/teameh/sass-css-components-fail-example/blob/master/loaders/log-source-loader.js)
- `no-css-modules`: SASS + [Custom source logging module](https://github.com/teameh/sass-css-components-fail-example/blob/master/loaders/log-source-loader.js)

Only the first and the last branch run without errors.

I've created the log-source example to see what the sass-loader is returning and [it looks like it's not transforming the sass](https://github.com/teameh/sass-css-components-fail-example/blob/master/webpack.log-source.log#L27;L50) (but this might also be me misinterpreting how the loaders work).

The other example without css modules does [show the right transformed](https://github.com/teameh/sass-css-components-fail-example/blob/master/webpack.no-css-modules.log#L12;L18) code..

I'm puzzled why the master branch (without postcss or another custom loader) is working fine though.. if something would be wrong with the sass-loader then that one should also fail right?

I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/288), but I'm thinking this has more chance on StackOverflow since it's such a specific problem and might be more a config problem. Here's my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-source-map',
  debug: true,
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  devServer: {
    outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new WriteFilePlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', [
          'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]_[name]_[local]',
          // 'postcss-loader',
          'sass'
        ])
      },
      // + js loader
    ]
  },
  postcss: [
    autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 0.5%'] })
  ],
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'loaders'),
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increase the `importLoaders` query parameter as you add loaders. That feature is poorly documented and confusing, but in your samples repo, `importLoaders=2` with both Sass and PostCSS works.

Comment: Yeah that worked!! Thanks so much! Found it here.. https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#importing-and-chained-loaders